# Login to LDAP with Kerberos password from PHP

Tags: php, ldap, kerberos

I'm trying to connect to my LDAP Server which uses Kerberos for password management. As far as I know, we can't send plaintext password, but I have to get a Kerberos token before.

Is it possible to do it all from PHP, without using mod_auth_kerb for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_auth_kerb won't help you either. It authenticates user requst for the Apache web server. Why do you think this could help you? There is no link between your problem and the module unless you want to use credential delegation.

Simply, there seems to be no real support in PHP for this. You could evaluate these:

1. try PHP LDAP SASL with GSSAPI mech: [1](http://objectmix.com/php/501722-phps-ldap_sasl_bind-tries-authenticate-krb5ccname-other-than-one-provided-mod_auth_kerb.html), [2](http://www.issociate.de/board/goto/440026/PHP_5.0.2_&_LDAP_SASL_Binds_%28GSSAPI_specifically%29.html), [3](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30819) and [4](http://www.google.de/search?hl=de&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=XG5&rls=org.mozilla%3Ade%3Aofficial&q=php+sasl+gssapi+ldap&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=),
2. use Perl which supports [GSSAPI bind](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/Authen-SASL-2.15/lib/Authen/SASL/Perl/GSSAPI.pm#EXAMPLE).

Btw, [this](http://blog.spahan.ch/2010/01/httpkerberospython/) is a very similar problem. Should work the same way in PHP. Use google translate.